# Multiplying inside an HTML document

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I'm working on a web application on Google App Engine with Python as my backend language. Now, I need to calculate a particular value based on the user input and display it on my web page. Here's the concerned code sample:

```
<h4>Total Amount:{{disp.actual_price}}*{{quantity}}</h4>
```

Now I'm using Jinja 2 template for rendering my HTML pages. In the above example, 'disp.actual_price' is the value of the 'actual_price' attribute in my 'disp' entity of my Google App Engine datastore, while 'quantity' is a value passed on by the user. So basically, I'm unable to figure out a way to multiply these two variable values and displaying them on the webpage. If the actual_price is 300, and the value of 'quantity' is 2, then here's what gets displayed with my above code:

```
Total Amount:300*2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write it this way:

```
 <h4>Total Amount:{{disp.actual_price * quantity}}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the question is don't do it. I'll explain why in a moment.

The correct syntax to do what you are attempting to do is:

```
<h4>Total Amount:{{disp.actual_price*quantity}}</h4>
```

From the documentation

> There are two kinds of delimiters. {% ... %} and {{ ... }}. The first one is used to execute statements such as for-loops or assign values, the latter prints the result of the expression to the template.

In this particular case, either delimter would work fine. But you'd really want to use the second one. Your code didn't work because anything outside of the delimiter is treated as plain HTML. It has to be *inside* the delimiter to be treated as an expression.

But why is this wrong? You are mixing business logic with interface. Doing this means that the day you want to change the design of the page, or the workflow, you'll be juggling around business variables in the page. If the calculation got a little more complex, then your template does too. But worst of all, if you move to a different templating engine, then your entire application is screwed because all your business logic is stuffed inside the template.

To do this correctly you need to have a file that just does the calculations by itself. In your file where you have the template being called, you should import this logic file and call on the methods inside it. Thus, the method inside the file responding to the HTTP requests, might look like this:

```
#initialize template variable
totalAmount = importedLogicModule.calculateTotalAmount(disp.actual_price, quantity)
return template.render(totalAmount = totalAmount)
```

and the template would now be

```
<h4>Total Amount:{{totalAmount}}</h4>
```